# Why does this throw an error in Node.js with --harmony?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

In Chrome Canary and Node.js 0.12.3, the following code prints `p`.

```
  'use strict';
  let o = {
    name: 'o',
    foo: function() {
      ['1'].map(function() {
           console.log(this.name);
      }.bind(this));
    },
  };

  let p = { name: 'p' };

  o.foo.call(p); // p
```

In Chrome Canary the following code also prints `p`. But why does it throw a TypeError in Node.js 0.12.3 with the `--harmony` flag?

```
  'use strict';
  let o = {
    name: 'o',
    foo: function() {
      ['1'].map(() => {
           console.log(this.name);
      });
    },
  };

  let p = { name: 'p' };

  o.foo.call(p); // p in Chrome, TypeError in Node.js with --harmony
```

Put another way, why is `this` `undefined` when the second code snippet is run in Node.js?

Comment: Arrow functions are broken in node/io right now https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/issues/735

Comment: This is almost certainly due to the fact that Canary is using a more recent version of v8 than Node is (since Canary is intentionally bleeding-edge, while Node tries to keep it stable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply [due to a bug in the version of the V8 engine](https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/issues/735) that iojs and node use.  Chrome Canary uses an unstable version of V8 that has addressed this issue. When this fixed is rolled out to a stable version of V8, node/iojs should work the same way.

For now, you can use a tool like [`babel`](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your code.  Using `babel` with no flags on your code transpiles to:

```
function foo() {
  var _this = this;

  ['1'].map(function () {
    console.log(_this.name);
  });
}
```

Which does indeed print `p`.